# How do I color a table row correctly?

Tags: tables

I want to color a table row but there is problem. How can I color a row completely? (The table width should be equal to the text wide.)

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}

\begin{document} ‎‎
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
‎$‎V_{‎CN}^{*}‎$  & ‎$‎{{E}_{11}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ &‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{1}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{E}_{22}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{2}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{3}}‎$ \\
\hline
‎0.11 & 94.4168 & 0.149 & 2.2037 & 0.934 & 0.934 \\  
‎0.14 & 120.3846 & 0.15 & 2.2977 & 0.941 & 0.941 \\  
‎0.17 & 144.7714 & 0.149 & 3.4939 & 1.381 & 1.381 \\  
\end{tabular}‎
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
‎$‎V_{‎CN}^{*}‎$  & ‎$‎{{E}_{11}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ &‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{1}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{E}_{22}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{2}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{3}}‎$ \\
\hline
‎0.11 & 94.4168 & 0.149 & 2.2037 & 0.934 & 0.934 \\  
‎0.14 & 120.3846 & 0.15 & 2.2977 & 0.941 & 0.941 \\  
‎0.17 & 144.7714 & 0.149 & 3.4939 & 1.381 & 1.381 \\  
\end{tabular*}‎
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but when it is equal to width

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really, all you need are:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

and then, instead of `tabular*` use:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C CCC CCC} 
...
\end{tabularx}
```

Taking your example (slightly modified) and then making those changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl, amsmath, tabularx}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
‎$‎V_{‎CN}^{*}‎$  & ‎$‎{{E}_{11}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ &‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{1}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{E}_{22}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{2}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{3}}‎$ \\
\hline
‎0.11 & 94.4168 & 0.149 & 2.2037 & 0.934 & 0.934 \\
‎0.14 & 120.3846 & 0.15 & 2.2977 & 0.941 & 0.941 \\
‎0.17 & 144.7714 & 0.149 & 3.4939 & 1.381 & 1.381 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
%\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc ccc}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C CCC CCC}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
‎$‎V_{‎CN}^{*}‎$  & ‎$‎{{E}_{11}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ &‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{1}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{E}_{22}}\left( \text{GPa} \right)‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{2}}‎$ & ‎$‎{{‎\eta‎}_{3}}‎$ \\
\hline
‎0.11 & 94.4168 & 0.149 & 2.2037 & 0.934 & 0.934 \\
‎0.14 & 120.3846 & 0.15 & 2.2977 & 0.941 & 0.941 \\
‎0.17 & 144.7714 & 0.149 & 3.4939 & 1.381 & 1.381 \\
%\end{tabular*}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: However, it would be better to use a package like `siunitx` as well so that you can align your numbers properly. (Look at the second and third columns.)