# Table header color not working as i want

Tags: tables, colortbl

I want the header of my table to be red but as you can see in the example it is red but also it seems there is a white extra column left to it. I can not seem to figure out why it is there. And how to remove it and get it fully red.

Below example table:
[image: example table]

Below the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,hmargin=2cm,bottom=3cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[RGB]{227,24,24}\color{white}\large\bfseries Nr &\color{white}\large\bfseries IP & \color{white}\large\bfseries TL1 & \color{white}\large\bfseries TL2 & \color{white}\large\bfseries TL3 & \color{white}\large\bfseries TL4 & \color{white}\large\bfseries TL5 \\\hline 
    1. & 1.1.1.1 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    2. & 1.2.3.4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    3. & 5.5.5.5 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
    4. & 95.231.766.33 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    5. & 115.231.796.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    6. & 115.231.776.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    7. & 715.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    8. & 415.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    9. & 315.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    10. & 215.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    11. & 115.231.76.33 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    12. & 95.271.76.33 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    13. & 95.231.786.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    14. & 95.231.756.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    15. & 95.231.746.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    16. & 95.231.736.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    17. & 95.231.726.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    18. & 95.231.716.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the docmentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Comment: Related:[coloring entire row of tabular*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89679/134144) and [How do I color a table row correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337737/134144)

Comment: `tabular*` inserts space _between_ the columns, and that is what you are seeing with the white gaps. Forcing the columns apart just make the table harder to read so simplest is to use a normal `tabular`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i changed it into tabular without the asterisk but then i get the following error: l.156 \noindent\begin{tabular}{\columnwidth}
                                            {@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|l|l|l...

Comment: @L00n3y that isn't an error message, just a location. You presumably didn't delete the `{\textwidth}` argument that `tabular` does not have,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oops sorry my mistake. I dont have textwidth in my code

Comment: your example actually has `\columnwidth` but same thing

Comment: unrelated to the table but you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{fontspec}`  use the first if you use pdftex and the second if you use luatex or xetex, never use both. similarly never `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with luatex or xetex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you it worked! finally it worked, thank you for the suggestion about fontspec i will change it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabular*` inserts space between the columns, and that is what you are seeing with the white gaps. Forcing the columns apart just make the table harder to read so simplest is to use a normal `tabular`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want your tabular to have a width equal to the maximal width (which is probably not a good idea), you can use `{NiceTabular*}` of `nicematrix`. The built-in command `\rowcolor` of that environment will color the whole row as expected.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,hmargin=2cm,bottom=3cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\thead}{\color{white}\large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \arrayrulecolor[RGB]{227,24,24}
    \noindent\begin{NiceTabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llccccc}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
    \rowcolor[RGB]{227,24,24}\thead Nr &\thead IP & \thead TL1 & \thead TL2 & \thead TL3 & \thead TL4 & \thead TL5 \\ 
    1. & 1.1.1.1 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    2. & 1.2.3.4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    3. & 5.5.5.5 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    4. & 95.231.766.33 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    5. & 115.231.796.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    6. & 115.231.776.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    7. & 715.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    8. & 415.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    9. & 315.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    10. & 215.231.76.313 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    11. & 115.231.76.33 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ 
    12. & 95.271.76.33 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 
    13. & 95.231.786.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    14. & 95.231.756.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    15. & 95.231.746.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    16. & 95.231.736.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    17. & 95.231.726.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    18. & 95.231.716.33 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    \end{NiceTabular*}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]